# "set months" error when I starting a DatePicker object

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a error when I start a DatePicker object or DatePickerDialog: In mi Eclipse LogCat debug console show this message:

```
06-15 01:02:33.935: E/DatePicker(7667): set months
```

I've tried things and I've read post for two days, and is IMPOSSIBLE for me skip this error.
For code, nothing results. For xml file, nothing results... I am crazy whith this error.
I am copy exatly the android developer reference code, and the error show again.

```
public class GestionAlertas extends Activity
{

    private TextView mDateDisplay;
    private Button mPickDate;
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gestion_alertas);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }});

        updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
    {
        switch (id) 
        {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay );
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
    {
        mYear = year; mMonth = monthOfYear; mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplay();
    }};


    private void updateDisplay() 
    {
        mDateDisplay.setText( new StringBuilder().append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-").append(mYear).append(" ") );
    }
```

Please HELP me.

**Edit**

The logcat:

> 06-15 11:14:38.920: D/dalvikvm(25412): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 89K,
>   47% free 2895K/5447K, external 1249K/1288K, paused 16ms 06-15
>   11:14:38.995: D/InputTransport(25412): Input channel constructed:
>   name='40a1d3a8 com.hide.hide/com.hide.hide.GestionAlertas (client)',
>   ashmemFd=47, receivePipeFd=48, sendPipeFd=49 06-15 11:14:39.075:
>   I/ViewRoot(25412): !@FINISH DRAWING :
>   com.hide.hide/com.hide.hide.GestionAlertas 06-15 11:14:39.080:
>   I/ViewRoot(25412): !@finishDrawing is completed :
>   com.hide.hide/com.hide.hide.GestionAlertas
>
> 06-15 11:14:40.800: D/(25412): 1 <--- LOG
>
> 06-15 11:14:40.920: E/DatePicker(25412): set months <--------- **ERROR**
>
> 06-15 11:14:40.930: D/(25412): 2 <--- LOG
>
> 06-15 11:14:40.965: D/InputTransport(25412): Input channel
>   constructed: name='40a3e268 viernes, 15/jun/2012 (client)',
>   ashmemFd=50, receivePipeFd=51, sendPipeFd=52 06-15 11:14:40.985:
>   D/dalvikvm(25412): GC_CONCURRENT freed 97K, 46% free 3082K/5639K,
>   external 3162K/3530K, paused 2ms+3ms 06-15 11:14:41.070:
>   I/ViewRoot(25412): !@FINISH DRAWING : viernes, 15/jun/2012 06-15
>   11:14:41.075: I/ViewRoot(25412): !@finishDrawing is completed :
>   viernes, 15/jun/2012

The code:

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener escuchadorFecha = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) 
{
    mYear = year; mMonth = monthOfYear; mDay = dayOfMonth;

    edFecha.setText( String.valueOf(mYear) + "/" + String.valueOf(mMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(mDay)  );
}};
```

---

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) 
{

    switch( id )
    {
        case DLG_FECHA:
            Log.d("", "1");
            DatePickerDialog r = new DatePickerDialog(this, escuchadorFecha, mYear, mMonth, mDay );
            Log.d("", "2");
            return r; 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Obviously there is not xml object for this code.

Comment: There is no error message like that in the current source code. Do you have any other symptoms besides that message? What sort of device or emulator are you using that logs this message?

Comment: I just ran your code sample (minus the XML) and it executes fine on a HTC. Could you post the full logcat?

Comment: Only that error shows in my logcat. I not use a emulator beacause my computer is old (Fujitu-Siemens Amilo li 2020 whit Window Vista). I use a real devide, a Samsung Galaxy Note, and the error is persistant ever. Sam, in case of DatePicker object the XML code is test, Only minimum properties, name, layout_height... and show error.

Comment: no solutions for the problem?